# How to find the proportion of zeros for each column of a data frame within each group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have a data frame (example below) with a "range" column and many "var" columns. I need to find the proportion of zeros in each "var" column within each "range" group. The end goal is to create a graph for each var column showing where the proportion of zeros increases with range. However, I am getting stuck just trying to find the proportion of zeros.

Here is an example dataset (note the inclusion of NA values):

```
      id <- seq(16)
      range <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
      var1 <- c(40,1.2,0,0, 1.5,1.6,NA,NA,6,0,9,3,4,0,0,0)
      var2 <- c(20,6,7,11, 0,0,0,0,NA,2,3,3,6,9,9,0)
      var3 <- c(4,6,0,11, 9,8,7,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,9,8)
      var4 <- c(NA,0,0,NA, 4,6,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,8)
      df <- data.frame(id, range, var1, var2, var3, var4)
```

I tried creating a loop to calculate the proportion of zeros for each each column, using the group_by() function in dplyr, and then using mutate() to add a column for the proportion, but I do not know how to use an indexed value to signify my ith column in mutate:

```
    for(i in 3:length(ncol(df))){
    df_new<-df[ , c(1:2,i)]%>%
    group_by(range)%>%
    mutate(prop_zero = sum(names(df[,i])==0, na.rm = TRUE)/sum(names(df[,i]))
    }
```

I know there are many things wrong with this, but I am not sure how to proceed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `across` to loop over the 'var' columns, get the proportion by calculating the `mean` of a logical expression (`.x == 0`) grouped by 'range' within `reframe`

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
df %>% 
   reframe(across(starts_with("var"),
   ~ if(! 0 %in% .x) 0 else mean(.x== 0, na.rm = TRUE)), .by = "range")
```

-output

```
  range var1 var2 var3 var4
1     1 0.50 0.00 0.25 1.00
2     2 0.00 1.00 0.25 0.25
3     3 0.25 0.00 0.00 1.00
4     4 0.75 0.25 0.50 0.50
```